# Logstash field with a null fvalue

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm using logstash to parse a value like:

`|SERVLETSESSIONS=|`

My bit to capture it is:

`\|SERVLETSESSIONS=(?<servlet_sessions>[0-9]*)\|`

I do not get an error, and all my other fields match, but I think I should get an empty value like `"servlet_sessions" => ""` in my `stdout { codec => rubydebug } }` but I do not have the `servlet_sessions` key there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [keep_empty_captures](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-keep_empty_captures) parameter of the Grok filter configuration.

```
input {  stdin { }  }

filter {
  grok {
    keep_empty_captures => true
    match => { "message" => "\|SERVLETSESSIONS=(?<servlet_sessions>[0-9]*)\|" }
  }
}

output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

The above configuration results in the following output:

```
{
          "message" => "|SERVLETSESSIONS=|",
         "@version" => "1",
       "@timestamp" => "2015-09-09T13:44:52.754Z",
             "host" => "localhost",
 "servlet_sessions" => ""
}
```

Comment: agreed :) verbosity++